# WCF MaxPendingChannels setting vs MaxConnections

Tags: wcf, duplex

what is the relation between those properties? which one of them govern the number of clients connect to net.tcp reliable service?

I tried to read on both of them but tit is not clear which control what in the throtlling  of the service

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful.

MaxPendingChannels has to do with the number do number of clients that can connect to a service via reliable session.

[When the sender creates a reliable session channel to a receiver, a handshake between them establishes a reliable session. After the reliable session is established, the channel is put in a pending channel queue for acceptance by the service. The MaxPendingChannels property indicates how many channels can be in this state.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms733795(v=vs.100))

MaxConnection behavior depends if it is set on the client or the server: On the client, it's a limit on the connections that are pooled, and on the server it's a limit on connections that haven't been accepted yet by the ServiceModel layer, [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxconnections?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this property describes the same thing, the number of channels that clients can connect to at the same time. With one difference, the default Concurrencymode for the WCF service is concurrencymode.single, which limits the number of connections a customer can make. In this mode, maxconnection represents the maximum number of connections allowed to be pending dispatch on the server, and maxpendingchannels refers to the number of connections for a reliable session.